# Return line of data with most recent date

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using Oracle SQL and trying to return the most recent `category` dependent on the `most_recent_date`.  I am able to successfully pull the `most_recent_date` per `category` per `part no/niin`, but I'm not able to get the full results I need.

I have the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    contract,
    part_no,
    niin,
    category,
    MAX(date_entered) OVER(PARTITION BY contract, part_no, niin, category) most_recent_date
FROM
    ( **inner query** )
```

Current result:

```
CONTRACT    PN  NIIN 1T 01-AUG-08
CONTRACT    PN  NIIN 7T 19-APR-22
```

My End result for this needs to be just the line that has the most recent date. Line needed below:

```
CONTRACT    PN  NIIN 7T 19-APR-22
```

I have tried to nest the select statement again, to then try and choose the most recent line, but still received the same 2 lines.  I also tried to use `most_recent_date` within a grouping statement for `category` and that didn't work either.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you could use `group by` and the `keep` syntax to bring the category that corresponds to the latest date:

```
select contract, part_no, niin, 
    max(date_entered) last_date,
    max(category) keep(dense_rank last order by date_entered) last_category
from ....
group by contract, part_no, niin
```

Answer (score 1):

The ROW_NUMBER function assigns a number to each row based on the order of the dates they were entered, starting from 1 for each category. So, the row with the most recent date within each category will have the number 1.

In the outer query, we select only the rows where the assigned number is 1. This means we are choosing the row with the most recent date for each category.

```
    SELECT CONTRACT, PN, NIIN, CATEGORY, DATE_ENTERED
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONTRACT,
        PN,
        NIIN,
        CATEGORY,
        DATE_ENTERED,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTRACT, PN, NIIN, CATEGORY ORDER BY DATE_ENTERED DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        ( **inner query** )
) subquery
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: The partition by should be `PARTITION BY contract, part_no, niin, category` !

Comment: This partially worked, but I had to tweak it to have the contract and PN be in the row_number aggregation.  1T and 7T are the only options so the above didn't allow me to see the most recent category on a part/niin level.

Comment: @SelVazi fixed! thanks for commenting